# Open USB Camera using OpenCV

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, camera, usb

I want to open a USB camera with OpenCV in C++ operating on Linux Mint 18.3.

The Camera is plugged in and works fine with the SoftwareSuite by Common Vision Blocks.

From command `lsusb` I got the following output:

```
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 1ab2:0001  
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0cf3:e300 Atheros Communications, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1bcf:2b95 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

The first entry seems to be the camera because the entry doesn't exist if the camera is unplugged. But I don't understand why there isn't a name shown.

Then I found on the internet that the USB camera is found under the path:
`/dev/v4l/by-id/ or /dev/v4l/by-path/`. The entry for `/dev/v4l/by-id/` is:

```
usb-CNFEH73N3462520017B2_Integrated_Webcam_HD-video-index0
```

and the entry for `/dev/v4l/by-path/` is:

```
pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:12:1.0-video-index0
```

So I want to open it with OpenCV by using:

```
VideoCapture 
cap("/dev/v4l/by-id/usb-CNFEH73N3462520017B2_Integrated_Webcam_HD-video-index0");
```

I use Clion as an IDE and run it normally as root, but in both cases I get the following error:

```
GStreamer Plugin: Embedded video playback halted; module source reported: Could not read from resource.
OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (GStreamer: unable to start pipeline) in cvCaptureFromCAM_GStreamer
/opencv-3.0.0/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp, line 773 terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
```

How can I open the USB camera and being on the right way to open it with `dev/v4l/`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should open a device by int id. Try with:

```
VideoCapture cap(0);
```

In fact, passing a string OpenCV expects to open a playback file, an MPEG file for example, as described in the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/videoio/doc/reading_and_writing_video.html).

This is working but the problem is that the opened camera is the integrated camera, the one reported by `lsusb` as:

```
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1bcf:2b95 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc.
```

which actually is `/dev/video0`, linked by:

```
/dev/v4l/by-path/pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:12:1.0-video-index0
```

Instead the `lsusb` entry listed as:

```
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 1ab2:0001
```

which is the externally plugged camera, seems not recognized as V4L device. I don't know "SoftwareSuite by Common Vision Blocks", so I have no idea, whether this software is able to work with it as RAW device.

Comment: Thaks for the answer. With

    > VideoCapture cap(0);

i open my webcam and if i try there an other id like id = 1 then the following error is shown.

>    VIDEOIO ERROR: V4L: index 1 is not correct!

and the programm open by default my webcam. Because in the internet i found too, that you can open the usb camera with id = 1, but it works only id = 0

Comment: id=0 represents the first webcam (`/dev/video0`, that should be what `/dev/v4l/by-id/usb-CNFEH73N3462520017B2_Integrated_Webcam_HD-video-index0` is linked to). Since you don't seem to have another webcam from your `lsusb`, it's normal you don't have device with id=1.

Comment: thanks, but the camera works with CVB and this entry Bus 002 Device 005: ID 1ab2:0001 shown by lsusb is only there when the camera is plugged in.
But how can i get acces to the usb cam?

Comment: id=0 is the first webcam independently of where it's enumerated in the USB bus. If you have only one camera, it's number is `0` for OpenCV. If you have two, they are `0` and `1`, for OpenCV. I don't understand. How many cameras have you attached??

Comment: i have two cameras. At firtst my integrated webcam and the second one is plugged in via usb. And i want to get open the usb camera with open cv

Comment: Ah - now it's clear - you should make it clearer in the problem description. I guess that you camera is not recognized as V4L device, while CVB is able to handle it, but I cannot help here. Try adding details, as the camera model, in the question - and describe better the actual problem you are facing

Comment: I have better formatted you question, but "usb-CNFEH73N3462520017B2_Integrated_Webcam_HD-video-index0" is the integrated webcam - it's an USB camera as well as in all the laptops, 4th or 5th line in `lsusb`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think i have found the solution. I have to create a xml file with the camera settings inside and then open the xml with my application. like its explained in this link: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d94/tutorial_camera_calibration.html

Comment: @Mahadumani: If you have solved your own problem, we appreciate it if you answer your own question below (in the Answers section, not as a comment). Please do show the relevant code as adapted from the link, so others can learn from you.