# Specify path of usb devices connecting with raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, usb, udev

I'm using raspberry pi, connecting two usb devices at the same time, incluing a arduino nano and one usb camera.
Each of them can work properly when separately running with code (plug in only one device to raspberry pi), where the default path is /dev/ttyUSB0 or /dev/video0.
However, when I plug in both two usb devices, arduino takes the default path, and the camera path is not accessible.
I've tried adding udev rules:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="tty",ATTRS{idProduct}=="7523",ATTRS{idVendor}=="1a86", SYMLINK+="arduino">
SUBSYSTEM=="tty",ATTRS{idProduct}=="6001",ATTRS{idVendor}=="038f", ,SYMLINK+="camera1">
```

Then I tried to call camera in c, still get error:

```
Open dev/camera1: No such file or directory
```

Is there any other way to specify the usb device path or port? I appreciate a lot for your help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Open USB Camera using OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54309848/open-usb-camera-using-opencv)

Comment: What C-library do you use to open the camera or device? Please show the portion of the code as [example].